# Microtime to Relative Date Conversion

Tags: php, microtime, relative-date

I am receiving the following value from a database which is a millsecond (microtime) value

> 1369057622.4679

I would like to output this in PHP to be

> 3 Day's ago

Essentially reading the milliseconds value and converting it to a relative date string, can anyone suggest an easy method to do this.

Comment: microtime() gives the current microtime. If you subtract the two, you get the difference in microseconds. You can divide in increments to get days: $days = floor($diff/1000/60/60/24); I added floor so you don't get 3.1231234213451234912873519875 days.

Comment: If you want more flexibility (not just showing days, but weeks or hours it they are more significant), look up [DateTime::Diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) and the resulting `DateInterval` object. It's more overhead to create the object than simple division, but then you have the tool to format your output any way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the following:

```
$input = 1369057622.4679;

$diff = floor(($input-time())/86400); // calculating the difference

$result = abs($diff) . (abs($diff)==1 ? ' day ':' days ') . ($diff<=0 ? 'ago':'ahead'); // making the result.
echo $result; // output: 1 day ago
```

Comment: The diff should be based on microtime(), not time(). The input the user is using is in milliseconds. The time function returns seconds. So, you are subtracting seconds from milliseconds.

Comment: @kainaw That's exactly what I thought on first look, but the input is not in milliseconds, it's in seconds and what comes after the `.` is considered as milliseconds, but since the OP wants the output in days we can "floor" the value because the milliseconds part isn't really relevant. Try to do `echo time();`, the result is `~1369138801`, compare it with `1369057622.4679`.